# Visualizing build steps in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline, I trigger several other jobs using the [build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Build+Step+Plugin) and pass some parameters to it. I'm having issues visualizing the different jobs I've triggered in addition to my pipeline. I have set up the [Jenkins Delivery Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) but the documentation for it is extremely vague and I have only been able to visualize the steps within my pipeline, despite tagging the jobs with both a stage and task name.

Example:

I have two jobs in Jenkins as pipelines/workflow jobs with the following pipeline script:

Job Foo:

```
stage('Building') {
    println 'Triggering job'
    build 'Bar'
}
```

Job Bar:

```
node('master') {
    stage('Child job stage') {
        println 'Doing stuff in child job'
    }
}
```

When visualizing this with the Jenkins Pipeline Delivery plugin, I only get this:
[image: Pipeline view]

How do I make it also show the stage in job Bar in a separate box?

Comment: AFAIK, It is not possible at this point of time with either Delivery Pipeline or Jenkins Pipeline View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this use case is currently not supported in the Delivery Pipeline plugin version 1.0.0. The delivery pipeline plugin views for Jenkins pipelines are only rendering what is contained within one pipeline definition at this point. This feature request is tracked in [JENKINS-43679](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43679).